# how to make notepad++ unknown tag highlight to known highlight?

Tags: html, notepad++

In HTML5, there are many new property/tag such as "required" for input validation.
It is unknown tag in Notepad++ (it is unknown highlight).

I want to know if I can make it as known tag?!

I found the langs.model.xml file for keywords but it doesn't work for tags.

Comment: You can add plugins to notpad++ to improve it. One is called `HTML tag`

Comment: I didn't see highlight feature on the HTML tag